# Java - a better way to ignore invalid records when parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, exception, collections

I know that it's a bad practice to use Exceptions for flow control. But I faced the following situation: I need to parse JSON file, and if there are corrupted values for the key of a record I want to just log it and continue to parse another object from `jsonArray`.  And even if the value is null I want to ignore it and go on.

So in my current implementation I use a try/catch block with continue. What would be a more correct approach here?

Here is how I've implemented it:

```
public static void parseMetrics(JSONParser parser, File jsonFile,
                             String metricKey, List<String> metricsList) throws IOException, ParseException {

        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsonFile)));
        for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                String metricValue = (String) jsonObject.get(metricKey);
                Long metricDate = parseDate(jsonObject);
                metricsList.add(new Metric(metricValue, metricDate));
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                continue;
                log.error("Error when parsing JSON", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no need of `continue` in the catch block.

Comment: Which object and method throw the exception ?  Note that the `continue` prevents the logging statement below.

Comment: Try to create a separe method `isJSONValid` check the valid JSON and there only use try and catch block.

Comment: @davidxxx `parser.parse` throws `ParseException`, `parseDate` throws `java.text.ParseException`

Comment: This is not the case of flow control by exceptions. You are logging the exception and continuing the other fields. Just remove the continue statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you want to log with the `error` level the parsing problem. 
So throwing a exception makes sense.
If the parsing error is an abnormal situation you should keep your way but just without the `continue` that is not convenient here :

```
for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String metricValue = (String) jsonObject.get(metricKey);
        Long metricDate = parseDate(jsonObject);
        metricsList.add(new Metric(metricValue, metricDate));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {         
        log.error("Error when parsing JSON", e);
    }
}
```

But if you consider that the parsing problem is not an issue to log but a normal scenario that *may* happen, indeed you don't have to propagate the exception from `parseDate()` but you could return something like `OptionalLong` instead of `Long`.
It would give from the client side :

```
for (Object obj : jsonArray) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    String metricValue = (String) jsonObject.get(metricKey);
    OptionalLong metricDate = parseDate(jsonObject);
    metricDate.ifPresent(d -> metricsList.add(new Metric(metricValue, d));           
}
```

You could also add a log in `debug` or info `level` if it makes sense.